# NavigationItemSelectedListener not calling while using multiple interfaces

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a navigation drawer in my main activity and i'm implementing 2 extra interfaces in that class. When i try to implement the 3rd one my OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is not getting invoked.

Below is my code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),

NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
ProjectListSelectionListener, IProgressViewLoader
{

  private var selectProjectData: ProjectDetails? = null
  private lateinit var progressView: View

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    setNavMenus()

    changeMainView(-1)
  }
}
```

And this is where i set the fragments listener

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        fragment = ProjectListFragment().apply {
                selectionListener = this@MainActivity
                progressLoader = this@MainActivity
         }
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

If i remove this line `progressLoader = this@MainActivity` it works. Also if i remove the IProgressLoader then also it works. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: No error is there. onNavigationItemSelected() this fun is never getting called when i try to implement IProgressLoader and ProjectSelectionListener together

Comment: Did you set `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`? Where do you call `navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)`?

Comment: i'm call that in onCreate fun. The issue comes when i do like this 
fragment = ProjectListFragment().apply {
                    selectionListener = this@MainActivity
                }

Comment: Add `onCreate` fun of `MainActivity` and part of `ProjectListFragment` where you call `onNavigationItemSelected()`.

Comment: How you determine that `onNavigationItemSelected` is not getting invoked?

Comment: when i'm setting this line  progressLoader = this@MainActivity, the function is not getting invoked, otherwise its working fine

Comment: Did you add logs or you just see that drawer isn't work?

Comment: i just saw the drawer isn't working. No error in console or logcat

Comment: Most likely the problem is inside `ProjectListFragment`. Can you add code of this class?

Comment: Did you use git? Can you add link to your project, so I'll be able quickly find a bug.